# Excel Macro in CSV

Tags: excel, csv, export-to-excel, vba

Is there any way to run an Excel Macro in CSV file format?

I am exporting a file to CSV using a csv template, Is it possible to write macros on the template which is in CSV format. I cant have it in XLS format. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: you can create a macro in an xls file and run it into csv file

Comment: Actually i'm using CSV template and generating a report from that template, which is also in CSV. This is bieng done by java class, where i cudnt modify the extension to xls. So i have to write macro in csv template , so when ever report is generated, macros shuld run.

Comment: macros are written in VBA and run from within Excel. Are you looking at exporting the macro code to the csv file?

Comment: I have tried creatin macro in xls and change extension to .csv, which actually runs the macro but it corrupts the data..

Comment: @fduff not looking to export macro into csv..but to write to csv file with macros in it using vba..and which cud be run using excel..

Comment: @roshanK: have you considered using `VBScript`/`vb6 Exe`/`Vb.net Exe` to run your macro on csv?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While you can't *save* a macro inside a `CSV` file you can either

1. Run the macro on the `CSV` using a controller workbook, or an addin
2. Go a step further and programmatically add code to the `CSV` file (for example to add an Event handler)

If you provide more information as to what you need to do then we can help with the paths above.

**(*Edit: it still isn't clear how the CSV file is generated - is this done via Excel or by another app?]***

Using Pearson's [Application Events example](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/AppEvent.aspx) you could use the code at bottom (from an open Excel controller workbook) to capture the addition of a new `CSV` file and then format it.

If you need to catch the creation of the `CSV` file on the fly then a more complex approach such as using [VBscript with WMI](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2004/10/11/how-can-i-automatically-run-a-script-any-time-a-file-is-added-to-a-folder.aspx) is necessary.

**`Controller Workbook Approach`**

*ThisWorkbook Module*

```
Private XLApp As CExcelEvents

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set XLApp = New CExcelEvents
End Sub
```

*class module called CExcelEvents*

```
Private WithEvents App As Application

Private Sub App_NewWorkbook(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
If Wb.FileFormat = xlCSV Then
MsgBox Wb & " is a Csvfile"
'your code
End If
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set App = Application
End Sub
```

Comment: I need to trigger an open event of workbook..which actually formats the csv report. CSV template is in server machine, is it possible to run code, so when end user generates a report from the template, open event should run at generated CSV file.

Answer (score 2):

**Setup**: Excel 2010

Save the macro that you created to Personal Macro Workbook.

**Details**:

1. Open a *.csv file
2. Record a macro and store it in Personal Macro Workbook.
3. Exit Excel and click Save when a message box asks if you want to save changes that you made to the Personal Macro Workbook.

[Link to the information source.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-and-save-all-your-macros-in-a-single-workbook-66c97ab3-11c2-44db-b021-ae005a9bc790)

Answer (score 0):

To acheive what you want to do, you need to first create an XLS with your desired macro VB code in it. Then you need to save this XLS somewhere that is always available (ie. on HD, or on corporate network). Then you need to create a custom button within Excel on your machine and link this button to your VB Macro Module that you desire to fire. This will then mean that whenever you open Excel manually, or via opening a CSV, then you will have the custom button in the toolbar just like any other. Then when the CSV is open in Excel you can click the custom button and it will fire off the macro that you linked it to, from the saved XLS whereever that is.

Comment: but its server client application...its not practical to create custom buttons on all client machine..

Comment: Sorry, but I hadn't read your comment about using a Controller Workbook, as meaning add a macro from an external XLS to the Quick Access Toolbar - which is why I suggested it as it is the quickest and simplest way to run external macros on open worksheets (without actually having the macro XLS open).

Comment: As @brettdj has already pointed out, you can not save a macro within a CSV file. A CSV file is merely a flat ascii file and will not house anything other than plain text. If you do not have the ability to change anything on the client machines that are opening this CSV, then I do not see you have many options, other than those suggested - A custom Add-In that opens when Excel opens is an option, or the custom button on the ribbon as I already suggested (which is seamless and quick).